# bad pc performance, benchmarking shows issues slow hardware

Tags: performance, windows-11, hardware-acceleration

I recently had trouble with a new game (freezing and crashing) on my desktop.  I completed reloaded Windows 11 and am now trying to make sure everything is running right.  But looking at these benchmarks I dont think it is.
I was hoping someone could give me some recommendations on things to try here. Maybe I need to overclock, but how would I know what value to set in bios?  FYI I have already updated drivers and bios (1107).

UserBenchmark app [results](https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/55289028) (FYI this shows ddr2, but it is ddr3 ram chips) shows that many of my components are performing under expectations

CPU: Intel Core i7-920 - 49.6%

SSD: Sandisk X400 M.2 2280 128GB - 55.2%

HDD:  WL1000GSA6472C 1TB - 101.2%

HDD: WD Blue 4TB (2015) - 91.7%

RAM: Unknown 6x2GB - 34.4%

MBD: EVGA 131-GT-E767

also tried cpu z, but results where to large to put here, your can see them [shared here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnekkr0bkkdmfg7/cpu%20z%20results.txt?dl=0)

**UPDATE 1**

downgraded to windows 10, updated, enabled turbo mode in bios and reran the [userbenchmark](https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/55294042)
not to much different, still reports DDR2 instead of DDR3 for whatever reason.

Comment: 1. Your system does not meet the minimum requirements to run Windows 11.  2. You are running a system with DDR2.  3. What are the system requirements for the application you are running?

Comment: Running a non-official version of Windows 11 on hardware which is unsupported by the official version is a recipe for disaster. What did you expect? Install Windows 10 and move on with your life.

Comment: @Ramhound That motherboard uses DDR3, not 2. Ditto for the CPU.

Comment: thanks guys, ill upgrade the ram to ddr3, and consider downgrading windows.  in terms of the ssd, its a pci card that has a sata port out the back of it, which goes to the 6gb sata port on the board.

Comment: DDR3 is the **only** RAM supported by your motherboard. If you managed to jam DDR2 in there then you would have physically broken your motherboard. Those test results are WRONG; presumably because you're running Windows 11 on unsupported hardware.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - The author linked to [this](https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/55289028) which indicates they have 12 GB of DDR2.

Comment: the other link, for cpuz results, does show them as ddr3.  ill downgrade to windows 10 and re-run test

Comment: @Ramhound and DDR2 on a Core i7-920 sounded accurate to you?

Comment: @owengerig - First, I assume you mean PCIe not PCI, there is a huge difference. The M.2 SSD you have is SATA III, so other than the obvious performance loss of it being a SATA III drive instead of PCIe that shouldn't be a source of any problems.  It's certainly faster than a mechanical drive.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - It's the correct era considering it's a 14 year old processor.  However, given the processor require DDR3, I concede my confusion.

Comment: @owengerig - You need to [edit] your question to indicate correct specifications in that case.

Comment: Turbo Mode is supported but disabled according to CPU-Z.  Turning that on in the bios might help.

Comment: fyi updated post after taking some suggestions here

Comment: I'd suggest using a different benchmark. 3DMark has some results for [systems like yours](https://www.3dmark.com/search#advanced?test=spy%20P&cpuId=900&gpuId=1092&gpuCount=1&gpuType=ALL&deviceType=ALL&storageModel=ALL&memoryChannels=0&country=&scoreType=overallScore&hofMode=false&showInvalidResults=false&freeParams=&minGpuCoreClock=&maxGpuCoreClock=&minGpuMemClock=&maxGpuMemClock=&minCpuClock=&maxCpuClock=). Run 3DMark Time Spy and if results are closer to expected, assume that UserBenchmark is broken.